# Select subsets of elements of a list under a certain condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new in *Mathematica* and am stuck on a simple problem. Please advise:

I have the following list:

```
list = {
{"1", 1000},
{"2", 800},
{"3", 800}
};
```

I want to select subsets of the first elements `Subsets[list[[All,1]]]` when the `Total` of coresponding second elements is for example $>= 1000$.

So in this example the expected result is:

> ```
>  {{"1"}, {"1", "2"}, {"1", "3"}, {"2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
> ```

I solved it using @Kuba's answer below, and added DeleteDuplicates to make it work better (produce less output) on large datasets:

```
lst = DeleteDuplicates[
If[
Total[#[[;; , 2]]] >= 1000, 
    #[[;; , 1]]] & /@ (Rest@ Subsets[list]) /. Null -> Sequence[]
] 
// TableForm
```

Comment: Did you mean `>=1000`? If I understand correctly your expected result should be `{{1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3}}`.

Comment: Since I know what you want, I have edited your question so it should be clear now. Feel free to undo if you wish.

Comment: @Kuba the guy said the output should be {"2","3"}. Surely he knows what he wants?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch You are right, but at least now the question is self consistent. We will see how he respond to that edit.

Comment: I wonder - how long is your initial list? `Subsets` has limits, so to speak... (especially on "unbounded" length of subsets). Say, you use `list = Table[{i, RandomInteger[{500, 1100}]}, {i, 20}]` (i.e. 20 elements in the initial list), on my machine, @Kuba's code takes 8sec (and on 25 elements, I didn't wait for it to finish. You **could** do `With[{subsets = Subsets[list, {1, \[Infinity]}]}, 
 Pick[subsets[[All, All, 1]], 
  UnitStep[Total /@ subsets[[All, All, 2]] - 1000], 1]]` which has the same problem, but better speed. So if the list is considerably longer, you'd need another approach...

Comment: @PinguinDirk I have a short list now (15 elements) but I want it to work up to thousands of elements (e.g. 2000) ...  mmm so that would take like... forever?

Comment: consider that `Subsets` on a list of length `n` generates a list with `2^n` items - try for instance `Subsets[Range[100]]`... so it breaks down (Mathematica is smart enough not to generate that list, it seems)

Comment: @PinguinDirk do you know of any alternatives? I suppose I could select sets of 10 or less elements to make the number of subsets smaller? I only would have no clue how to do that...

Comment: well, it's hard to judge not knowing what this is all about. breaking up the problem in a smart way might be a way (depending on the input) - but be aware that if you say have 2000 elements each >=1000, you'd get 2^2000 results (i.e. just as many as there are subsets). I guess you need to get more context (and maybe not accept an answer too quickly, as others won't look at the Q anymore)

Comment: @PinguinDirk should I edit my question and unaccept the answer then (I am new to stackexchange so I don't know what the 'normal' way is)?

Comment: Well, I can't tell, not knowing what it is all about. Somewhere they write: "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.". So you have to decide how to proceed. If @Kuba's idea works for you, ignore me & my comments - if it doesn't I am sure Kuba won't be mad at you for "unaccepting" :). Further, if you unaccept, you might want to clarify things.

Comment: This Q&A is complete in general form, and is not going to be efficient, it just can't. But if you add all the info about the data and the contex, we can work on it. Maybe a separate question is an idea? @PinguinDirk Totally agree :) Also, your remark about computational complexity is very important.

Comment: I will work on my problem some more and then post a seperate question where I provide more context! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you asked for:

```
If[
   Total[#[[ ;; , 2]]] >= 1000,
   #[[ ;; , 1]]
  ] & /@ (Rest@Subsets[list]) /. Null -> Sequence[]
```

> ```
> {{"1"}, {"1", "2"}, {"1", "3"}, {"2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
> ```

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to select subsets between certain values. I like your answer a lot, you made me understand how to do it!! For example, a slight tweak gives me exactly what I want:

Comment: If[1000 > Total[#[[;; , 2]]] > 100, #[[;; , 1]]] & /@ (Rest@
    Subsets[list]) /. Null -> Sequence[]

Comment: @sanderws I'm glad you find it useful :) Please do not accept so fast, there are going to be more great answers if you edit your question to be more clear. :)

Comment: I would like to ask a follow up question. However I find it hard to formulate it so I would like to show you how I used your answer and what I would like to do next. I just figured out that you cant use the same markup in comments as in questions but It seems much to start a new question. What is a smart way to follow up? @kuba

Answer (score 4):

```
u = Rest @ Subsets[list];
#[[;; ,1]]& /@ Pick[u, (Total[#[[;;, 2]]] >= 1000)& /@ u]
```

yields

```
{{"1"}, {"1", "2"}, {"1", "3"}, {"2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Select`:

```
list = {{"1", 1000}, {"2", 800}, {"3", 800}};

ssets = Transpose /@ Subsets[#, {1, Length@#}] &;

Select[ssets[#], Total@#[[2]] >= 1000 &][[All, 1]] &@list

(*{{"1"}, {"1", "2"}, {"1", "3"}, {"2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{"1", 1000}, {"2", 800}, {"3", 800}};

Select[Subsets @ list, Total[#[[All, 2]]] >= 1000 &][[All, All, 1]]
```

{{"1"}, {"1", "2"}, {"1", "3"}, {"2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}

Answer (score 1):

For educational/illustrational purposes and to connect to the beautiful answer by @elso consider the following

```
testfunction = Total[#[[All, 2]]] >= 1000 &;
```

We can use [**`Cases`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[Subsets@list, argument_ /; testfunction[argument]][[All, All, 
  1]]
```

It should be noted that in this way @eldo's answer is re-written as:

```
Select[Subsets@list, testfunction][[All, All, 1]]
```

So, it should be obvious that [**`Select`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)and [**`Cases`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) with the difference that the former uses a function and the latter a pattern as can be read online in the documentation.